# how to upload excel file on jive via vba macro?

Tags: excel, jive, vba

I have to upload excel document on jive via vba macro. please let me know if it is possible via REST API or any other method

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using a Jive app in command line mode in VBA. Contact your Jive person to get this to you. First you have to download this app and install it in your system, and then you have to call this app with parameters through the Shell command.

I used the below code to accomplish this.

```
Public Sub ShellCmd()

    Dim strExe As String, strJiveInstanceURL As String, strFilePattern As String
    Dim usrID As String, Passwd As String, strcurlExtra As String

    strExe = "The Jive exe file path"
    strJiveInstanceURL = "https://companyname.jiveon.com"
    strFilePattern = "c:/santosh/Test1.xlsx"
    usrID = "***" ' your user ID
    Passwd = "*******" ' your password
    strcurlExtra = "-x http://gateway.****.***:1234 --proxy-user your user       ID:Your password -k" ' proxy server settings

    Call Shell("""" & strExe & """" & " " & """" & strJiveInstanceURL & """" & " " & """" & _
strFilePattern & """" & " " & "test" & " " & """ """ & " " & """" & "99743" & """" & _
" " & "1 userID Password" & " " & """" & strcurlExtra & """", vbNormalNoFocus)

End Sub
```